# SQLite sequence of commands do not work

Tags: c#, sqlite

I created a class for managing SQLite commands to my DATA class.
The class `SQLiteManager` look like this:

```
class SQLiteManager : IDisposable
{    
    protected SQLiteConnection Conn;
    protected SQLiteCommand Cmd;

    public SQLiteManager(string fullfilename)
    {
         Conn = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}", fullFileName));
         Conn.Open();
    }

    public string Query(string query)
    {
         //Cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Conn); << obsolete!
         Cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
         Cmd.CommandText = query;
         return Cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         if (Conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
         {
             Conn.Close();
             Conn.Dispose();
         }
         GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~SQLiteManager()
    {
        Conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I use this class in my form in this way:

```
using (SQLiteManger sqlMgr = new SQLiteManger(fileName))
{
   // .... some stuff here
   MessageBox.Show(string.format("My first query: {0}", sqlMgr.Query("....query...")); // << this works
   MessageBox.Show(string.format("My second query: {0}", sqlMgr.Query("....query...")); // << this doesnt works - NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION comes out!
}
```

The second query gives a `NullReferenceException` even if I didn't close connection and I am into the using statement.
Debugging the behaviour is as follow:
At the second query the cursor comes into Query method, executes the method, but before the execution of `return Cmd.ExecuteScalar().toString();`
jumps to `Dispose()` method.... so the exception comes out.
I wonder why at the second query the program jumps to `Dispose()` even if I didn't require...

I removed and corrected as suggested by O.R.Mapper, and the answer to the `ExecuteCommand` question is:

Debugging, the second time the cursor doesn't reach the command `Cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.. because jumps to the `Dispose()` method.

**SOLVED**
the matter is due to `Cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` in `Query(string query)` method. The right `return` statement is:

```
        object value = Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return value != null ? value.ToString() : null;
```

Comment: In `Query(string)`, why do you assign two values in sequence to the `Cmd` variable? The first one is obsolete, it never gets used.

Comment: Also, is that your actual code? The method is called `ToString`, not `toString`, so what you have posted here shouldn't compile.

Comment: Other than that, can you debug stepwisely and check what is returned by `Cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: I updated my post thank to comments by O.R.Mapper

Comment: Going deeper into the matter, the second query doesn't give result due to missing value (i.e.: I asked to search something not present in the archve, so before 'return', the program jumps to _Dispose()_ release resources and this is the cause of message: 'NullReferenceExpection'. At this point I have to change the question: How Could I avoid 'NullReferenceException' and sort message like: "value not found"?